# Would an RIP Dennis Ritchie question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Clearly it isn't a question, but it seems somehow appropriate that the original author of the C programming language be commemorated in some fashion on StackExchange, and Programmers is the least off-topic site.

Answer (score 8):

This is already being address on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160/no-dennis-ritchie-quote-on-stack-overflow-why) with respect to a **message** on the network.

Personally I didn't think that the Steve Jobs message was appropriate, but I don't own the network.

As to your question about asking a **question**, then no, that wouldn't be appropriate at all. At best it's too localised.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie localised. As in there is no C code orbiting uranus? There is C code orbiting every other planet in the solar system, and, running on every continent, country, sea and ocean.

Comment: @JamesAnderson - I was thinking about the "moment in time" aspect in particular.

Comment: temporal localisation -- I get it!

Answer (score -4):

How about a "What was your first real C program".

It is answerable although the answers might not be considered useful, there, are bound to be some interesting answers.

Comment: "Getting to know you"-style questions are [not on-topic here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).